# Reinitializing Firebase Functions project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I already have a **Firebase functions** that are currently working fine. These functions were deployed when I was using **Windows** machine. Today I thought to modify something in the functions with my **Mac machine**. When I am trying to **reinitialize** the same project, the **index.js** comes with the default code without my functions that I deployed.

Following are the steps I am performing in order to reinitialize the project.

- firebae init
- Select: Functions: Configure and deploy Cloud Functions
- Use an existing project
- I am selecting my project name
- language: JavaScript
- Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes
- Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? (Y/n) Yes

Now, when I go and check the index.js in the function folder it has only one default code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
```

However, I can see the functions with my custom code at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions.

please help. Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing a project with the Firebase CLI doesn't not rebuild any source code that you might have previously deployed.  You should be storing that in some sort of source control, such as git, in order to share it between people, projects, and machines.  If you don't use source control, you will have to manually copy the files between machines.

Comment: Does it mean that if by mistake I deploy my newly build project functions, then my app will stop working as my previous functions will be overwritten?

Comment: I don't see how redeploying functions will cause an app to stop working, unless those deployed functions are broken.  People redeploy all the time to update their apps.  It doesn't matter where the deployment came from.

Comment: What I meant is, if I create a new project which comes with default index.js (without my existing code in the cloud functions) and I deploy the function without copying them back to my local index.js then my app will stop working...

Comment: The Firebase CLI will warn you if that's about to happen, but yes, you could end up deleting all the existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

### You can just re-run `firebase init functions` to regenerate the firebase config (**not** download your source code)

I had to reinitialize my firebase functions (title of the question) because I was getting some errors in `firebase-debug.log` about `firebase.json`. I deleted it and wanted to regenerate it. I didn't have the issue the question poster had (I guess he literally ran `firebase init` and expected the code to be transferred from his windows computer to his mac, which is why Doug said "you will have to manually copy the files between machines".)

---

I was getting the error, `Error: Not in a Firebase app directory (could not locate firebase.json)`. I ran `firebase init functions` in the root directory of the project which already had a `functions` directory, and the error was fixed.

The following showed up:

```
=== Functions Setup

A functions directory will be created in your project with sample code
pre-configured. Functions can be deployed with firebase deploy.

? What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? TypeScript
? Do you want to use ESLint to catch probable bugs and enforce style? Yes
? File functions/package.json already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/package.json
? File functions/.eslintrc.js already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/.eslintrc.js
? File functions/tsconfig.json already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/tsconfig.json
? File functions/tsconfig.dev.json already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/tsconfig.dev.json
? File functions/src/index.ts already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/src/index.ts
? File functions/.gitignore already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of functions/.gitignore
? Do you want to install dependencies with npm now? Yes
```